# MSpec, what should I put in my [Subject()] attributes?

Tags: tdd, bdd, mspec

I've been using MSpec for a little while and I really like it. I've found that to get ReSharper to recognize my specifications, I need to use a `SubjectAttribute`.

I'm wondering though, what's the best thing to put in the `[Subject()]` attributes?

If I'm doing BDD, then I don't know the type under test so `[Subject(typeof(thingy))]` seems premature. Could be added later I suppose once the code is written.

So that leaves the text version, `[Subject("some text")]`. But what's the best thing to put there?

Whatever I do, it doesn't seem to affect the output I get in ReSharper. I suppose to some extent this is down to personal preference, but I wondered if there was any convention here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to apply `SubjectAttribute` to have ReSharper recognize contexts and specifications, a class containing an `It` field will suffice. However, if you want ReSharper to support custom naming conventions for MSpec types and fields (`Because` et al) you need to apply the `SubjectAttribute`:

1. Define custom naming conventions in ReSharper | Options |
   Languages/Common section | Naming Style | Advanced Settings

   When you add a User defined naming rule scroll down the list to see MSpec entities.
2. Enable MSpec annotations in ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection/Code Annotations section

   Annotations + `SubjectAttribute` (even without custom naming rules) prevent ReSharper from marking MSpec's fields as unused. Alternatively, disable warning 169 in the project settings.

`Subject` serves as metadata describing you context, for example you can use the System Under Test (when writing a unit test), a string of your choice, or both. These information will be reported in the HTML and in the ReSharper output. It doesn't work as of now, I suspect this is a [bug](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications/issues/67) in the ReSharper runner for 6.0.

As with strings, you can basically put anything you want there. I would recommend using the subject to group your specs by feature.

Subject: Login

Contexts: When logging in with valid credentials, When logging in with invalid credentials, etc.

There's an [example in my GitHub repository](https://github.com/agross/mspec-samples/blob/master/WebSpecs/LoginApp.Watin.Specs/LoginSpecs.cs).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the information and particularly the link to the samples, I had not found those and I'm sure they will be valuable. I think perhaps that link deserves more prominent publicity :)

Comment: If you want to contribute ReSharper-specific documentation to our readme, a pull request is highly appreciated :)